# Boost on Update Document in Elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a scenario where I am storing URLs in documents in a particular index in Elasticsearch. Sometimes I get an existing URL multiple times. I want to use Elasticsearch to increment the number of times I encounter a particular URL. This is doable by using Update API with scripts. However, that sometimes seems to be slow and complex.

Is there a way in Elasticsearch to boost a document on updating an existing document? If yes, then I think I can use this to measure hits, as in I can boost everytime I encounter an existing URL and that will solve all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you update the boost of a document when you update, you have to delete + reindex the document anyway.  It won't save you any performance, but you will lose flexibility due to index-time boosting and reduced precision

It would be cleaner to simply increment a field and then use that field as a custom boost value later (using function_score, custom_score, etc).  Same performance overhead but much greater flexibility.  If you find it too slow to update the entire document, you can split the counter out into it's own document type which is dedicated to counters.  Since docs will only contain a single field they will update very quickly.

Comment: So that might work but I am not sure. Need to try. But when I was using counters in the same docs as URL, I noticed a lot of version conflicts. My setup is that I have 3 nodes with two data nodes and one non-data node and I write to the non-data node (which is also the master).

The reason behind version conflicts could be that the non-data node is acting as the LB in the cluster and when two URLs are encountered, we try to increment the counter but that might be happening on two different nodes at the same time, leading to version conflicts. Our indexing/updating load is about 8K/sec.

Comment: Updates to a document only occurr on the primary shard, so it doesn't actually matter how many nodes are in your cluster, or where you send the request. The update request will always be redirected to the single primary shard that holds the document. The version conflict is because ES uses optimistic concurrency control and two updates are racing each other on the same shard. Increase your `retry_on_conflict` and the updates will eventually "stick".